# jQuery: wrap every 2 words in div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to wrap every 2 words in a `<div>` tag. 
e.g. the desired output to look like this:
`<div>one two</div><div>three four</div><div>five six</div>` etc etc.
But what I'm actually getting, the first two words are being ignored, and I'm actually getting:
`one two<div>three four</div><div>five six</div>`
Here's my code,
HTML:

```
<h2><div>This is some long heading text to use as an example. This is some long heading text to use as an example</h2>
```

jQuery:

```
$("h2 div").each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html().split(" ");
    var newhtml = [];

    for(var i=0; i< html.length; i++) {

        if(i>0 && (i%2) == 0)
            newhtml.push("</div><div>");

        newhtml.push(html[i]);
    }

    $(this).html(newhtml.join(" "));
});
```

I've tried adding a `<div>` tag after the `<h2>` tag in the html to achieve this effect, but it still doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your HTML code is missing closing div tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

HTML: (no div in there yet)

```
<h2>This is some long heading text to use as an example. This is some long heading text to use as an example</h2>
```

JS (notice the last line):

```
$("h2").each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html().split(" ");
    var newhtml = [];

    for(var i=0; i< html.length; i++) {

        if(i>0 && (i%2) == 0)
            newhtml.push("</div><div>");

        newhtml.push(html[i]);
    }

    $(this).html("<div>"+ newhtml.join(" ") +"</div>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var html = 'This is some long heading text to use as an example.'.split(" ");
var newhtml = [];
for( var i=0 ; i<html.length-1 ; i+=2 ) newhtml.push(html[i]+' '+html[i+1]);
if( html.length&1 ) newhtml.push(html[html.length-1]);

'<div>'+newhtml.join('</div><div>')+'</div>'
```

The final line is the string `"<div>This is</div><div>some long</div><div>heading text</div><div>to use</div><div>as an</div><div>example.</div>"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a regex pro by any means, but just to offer a possible alternative, I think you could do this using something like:

```
string.replace(/(\S+ \S+)/g, "<div>$1</div>");
```

Like so:

```
$("h2 div").each(function(){
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/(\S+ \S+)/g, "<div>$1</div>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6JeFH/1/

Comment: An improvement on my idea!  It could be modified slightly to suit an odd number of words, though.

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly skip the first match in the loop, so adding `newhtml.push("<div>")` before the loop would help.
This still leaves the issue of you creating a div that is not closed, so adding `newhtml.push("</div>")` after the loop would be recommended aswell.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
<h2>This is some long heading text to use as an example. This is some long heading text to use as an example</h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("h2").each(function() {
        var html = $(this).html().split(" ");
        var newhtml = [];
        newhtml.push("<div>");

        for(var i=0; i< html.length; i++) {

            if(i>0 && (i%2) == 0)
                newhtml.push("</div><div>");

            newhtml.push(html[i]);
        }

        newhtml.push("</div>");

        $(this).html(newhtml.join(" "));
    });
</script>
```

Edit: Actually the code for Entoarox answer :)

Answer (score 0):

[Please have a look at the fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/robbmj/KshNL/1/)

**I have provided two examples**

The first does not rely on the html being initially malformed

```
<h2>
     <div>
          This is some long heading text to use as an example. 
          This is some long heading text to use as an example
    </div>
</h2>
```

And one where there is only the `<h2>` tag and an odd number of words

```
<h2>
    This is some long heading text to use as an example. 
    This is some long heading text to use as an example oddnumber
</h2>
```

The same JavaScript runs on both of them

```
$("h2 > div").each(divByTwo);
$("h2").each(divByTwo);

function divByTwo() {
    var html = $(this).html().trim().split(" ");
    var newhtml = [];   
    for(var i=1; i< html.length; i += 2) {
        newhtml.push("<div>" + html[i - 1] + " " + html[i]+ "</div>");       
    }

    if (html.length % 2 !== 0) {
        newhtml.push("<div>" + html[html.length - 1] + "</div>");
    }
    $(this).html(newhtml.join(" "));
}
```